# Add highlighting for [Laravel]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

There are [50,000+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel+-php) tagged with [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) but not [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), so there are many questions that I see under the tag that have no syntax highlighting (or it’s inconveniently added with an HTML comment).

Laravel is a PHP framework, so in theory these questions could be retagged to have the PHP tag, but this seems like a lot of work. And not all questions under the tag directly involve PHP either as Laravel also includes things like Artisan console commands.

Would it be possible to add highlighting to [laravel]?

It would make sense for the highlighting to either be PHP or default, the latter since some code would do better with HTML highlighting:

```
<div class="{{$color}}">
      {{$value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Sep 22 | moderator updates tag language format | taglaravel, old lang = , new lang = lang-php by BoltClock (yes, it really is that poorly formatted)]

lang-php comes with HTML highlighting on the side, so I went with that instead of lang-default.

Let me know if this causes unintended side effects on a significant number of questions.