# Add syntax highlighting to [primefaces] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Monitoring [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) and related tags, every now and then there are questions tagged [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) only and they are lacking syntax highlighting. In theory most of them can be tagged [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) as well, because

- [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) is a java  MVC web framework
- [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) is a commonly used [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf)-component framework.

Here are two examples where syntax highlighting is missing:

[Primefaces file upload several times problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552516/primefaces-file-upload-several-times-problem)

[Primefaces - Refresh Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434422/primefaces-refresh-datatable)

Being confused why some questions have syntax highlighting, and others do not, I found that [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) probably use `lang-default` syntax highlighting while [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) has no syntax highlighting defined.

I did not find how to (suggest) edits to a tag and [this QA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389616/add-highlighting-for-laravel) plus the fact that a change may impact a large number of posts suggest that only mods can do so.

From SE Data Explorer I found [3489 questions tagged primefaces but not jsf](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1146805/get-all-questions-with-tag-primefaces-but-missing-jsf). On a quick glance most of them have source code without syntax highlighting, some also answers without syntax highlighting. I'm sure it is not obvious for (especially new) users why syntax highlighting is missing in their posts and editing all these questions appears to be a lot of work.
As this tagging is kind of rare, technically I could imagine editing future questions to add [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) but I will surely miss a fraction of them. Also adding [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) "because syntax highlighting" appears to be an odd reason in my opinion.

Finally some [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) tagged questions are actually primefaces-only and **not** [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) questions - e.g. this one: [How to use a p:dataTable with p:columnGroup headers using p:columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413667/how-to-use-a-pdatatable-with-pcolumngroup-headers-using-pcolumns) where the [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) tag was explicitly and rightfully removed.

The most frequently used code languages for [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) tagged questions are `xhtml` and `java`. `default` syntax highlighting does a quite good job here and would also not conflict if the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag was added either.

So I ask that we add `default` syntax highlighting to the [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) tag in analogy to the [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) tag where it is already present.

Comment: `jsf` is set to use the `default` highlighter, the “best effort” highlighter. You can see this at the bottom of the tag wiki page.

Comment: And why not just add the [tag:jsf] tag to those pages?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your replay, please see my update of the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd say it's bad practice to simply tag questions as `jsf` just to have the correct syntax highlighting when a question clearly relates to a `primefaces` component and not to the underlying JSF working.